# Entity Framework group by on the included table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, group-by, sql-order-by

I've two tables joined in 1-n way.

First Table - **Users**:

[image]

Second Table - **Consent**:

[image]

In SQL Server i use this query

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
  Inner Join (
    Select Consent.IDUser, Consent.Type, Consent.Date, Consent.Consent
    From Consent
    Inner Join (
        Select IDUser, Type, Max(Date) as MaxDate
        From Consent
        Group By IDUser, Type
    ) As ConsentGrouped on Consent.IDUser = ConsentGrouped.IDUser and Consent.Type = ConsentGrouped.Type and Consent.Date = ConsentGrouped.MaxDate
  ) as AllData
  On Users.id = AllData.IDUser
```

to achieve this

[image]

In my .NET project i use entity framework, so i've this two entities:

```
    public partial class Users
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Users()
        {
            this.Consent = new HashSet<Consent>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Consent> Consent{ get; set; }
    }

public partial class Consent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IDUser { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Consent { get; set; }

    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
}
```

How can i obtain the same query result via Entity Framework? So only the most recent consent by type for each user.

I use this lambda to get the user, how can I modify it to obtain the desired result?

```
 var user = await db.Users
     .Include(ut => ut.Consent)
     .Where(ut => ut.Id == userID)
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests and several researches, I managed to solve using a complex lambda.

```
var user = db.Users
    .Where(ut => ut.Id == userID)
    .Select(b => new UsersResource
        {
            Id = b.Id,
            Name = b.Name,
            Surname = b.Surname,
            Consent = b.Consent
            .GroupBy(item => item.Type,
                (key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(gx => gx.Date).FirstOrDefault())
            .Select(st => new ConsentResource
                {
                    Id = st.Id,
                    IDUser = st.IDUser,
                    Type = st.Type,
                    Origin = st.Origin,
                    Date = st.Date,
                    Consent = st.Consent
                }).ToList()
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Awesome solution, Luciano. I believe you can use FirstOrDefault instead of ToList() since the select result is only one as you said

Comment: You are right! I had put ToList because FirstOrDefault was giving me an error, but now it works perfectly (I was confused, probably the error had to be somewhere else in the lambda). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here I used LINQ instead of lambda expressions because in this scenario lambda can be tricky sometimes, I also used explicit join so the explanation got easier to understand.

```
var query = (from user in users
                    join consent in consents
                        on user.Id equals consent.IdUser
                    group new {user, consent} by new {consent.Type, consent.IdUser} into g 
                    select new { 
                            g.FirstOrDefault().user.Id, 
                            g.FirstOrDefault().user.Name,
                            g.FirstOrDefault().user.SureName,
                            ConsentId = g.FirstOrDefault().consent.Id,
                            g.FirstOrDefault().consent.IdUser,
                            g.FirstOrDefault().consent.Type,
                            g.FirstOrDefault().consent.Origin,
                            Date = g.Max(m => m.consent.Date),
                            g.FirstOrDefault().consent.ConsentFlag
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Andre, Thanks for the support. I tried your query and it exactly returns the query result in sql server. I was unable to modify it to obtain the structured classes one by many, as the lambda that I posted returns. However, I found a different solution if you want to take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Luciano! What is the needed output? Checkout my comment in your answer :)